Unhandled Runtime Error: data is undefined in useSuspenseQuery with Next.js and Tanstack Query
I am working on a Next.js application where I have implemented a commenting system. Users can post a review for a particular AI tool, reply to a review, and reply to a reply as well.
I have a component named <ReplyItemOperations /> that renders three buttons: like, dislike, and reply. Inside this component, I am using useSuspenseQuery to fetch the status of whether the user has liked/disliked the reply or not.
Here is the code for the <ReplyItemOperations /> component:
import { useState } from "react"
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"
import { Reply, Review } from "@/types"
import {
  useMutation,
  useQueryClient,
  useSuspenseQuery,
} from "@tanstack/react-query"
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react"


type ReplyItemOperationsProps = {
  review: Review
  reply: Reply
}

export function ReplyItemOperations({
  review,
  reply,
}: ReplyItemOperationsProps) {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { data: session } = useSession()
  const user = session?.user
  const userEmail = session?.user?.email

  const {
    id: replyId,
    likes_count: initialLikesCount,
    dislikes_count: initialDislikesCount,
  } = reply

  const { id: reviewId, tool_name: toolName } = review

  const { data: userReplyData } = useSuspenseQuery({
    queryKey: ["userReplyData", toolName, userEmail],
    queryFn: async () => {
      if (!userEmail) {
        return null
      }
      return await getUserReplyData(toolName, userEmail)
    },
  })

  const [likesCount, setLikesCount] = useState(initialLikesCount)
  const [dislikesCount, setDislikesCount] = useState(initialDislikesCount)
  const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = useState(userReplyData?.is_liked || false)
  const [isDisliked, setIsDisliked] = useState(
    userReplyData?.is_disliked || false
  )

// Other component logic

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Component JSX */}
    </div>
  )
}

Here is the query code that fetches the data (an object with two keys: is_liked and is_disliked) regarding whether the current user has liked/disliked the reply or not:
const { data: userReplyData } = useSuspenseQuery({
    queryKey: ["userReplyData", toolName, userEmail],
    queryFn: async () => {
      if (!userEmail) {
        return null
      }
      return await getUserReplyData(toolName, userEmail)
    },
  })

And here is the code for the getUserReplyData() function:
import { supabase } from "@/lib/clients"

export async function getUserReplyData(
  toolName: string,
  userEmail: string | null | undefined
) {
  const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from("user_replies")
    .select("is_liked, is_disliked")
    .match({ tool_name: toolName, user_email: userEmail })
    .single()

  if (error) {
    console.error(`Error getting user replies data: ${error.message}`)
    return
  }

  console.log("Get user reply data: ", data)

  return data
}

The <ReplyItemOperations /> component is rendered inside the <ReplyItem /> component, and the <ReplyItem /> component is rendered inside the <Reviews /> component (where I display both the reviews and replies, including nested replies). The <Reviews /> component is rendered inside the <ToolPage /> component which display details regarding a particular AI tool (along with the reviews).
When I am NOT logged in, the <ToolPage /> component renders fine; I see the tool details, as well as the reviews and replies for that particular tool, as shoen below:

But when I am logged in, the <ToolPage /> does not render, and I get the following error:

Error: ["userReplyData","MakeAudio","user@gmail.com"] data is undefined

I suspect this error is related to the query key that I have set inside the query. Here is the query key for reference:
queryKey: ["userReplyData", toolName, userEmail],

So, why am I getting this error when I am logged in? Is it because the userEmail has a value when I'm logged in and is undefined when I'm not logged in, and this messes up the cache? If yes, how do I solve this problem?
Additional Information:

Next.js version: 14.1.3
Tanstack Query version: 5.40.1
next-auth version: 4.24.5

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Could it be your error handling? When you get an error from supabase, you're returning nothing, aka undefined. Perhaps you should throw an error instead
